# Model value is not getting reflected when changing the checkbox values using angular.element(document.querySelector(id)).attr('checked', true);

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a logic like i have four checkboxes which should behave as existed code. Logic is working. But i do check and uncheck using the syntax.

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+j)).attr('checked', true);

 angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+j)).attr('checked', false);
```

which is not reflected in the respective checkbox element's model value. As you can check the attached screen shot. First three box got checked but it shows 'true' for actual clicked element rest remains 'false'. I need the updated model values. Anyone can help on this !

Here is the working example https://plnkr.co/edit/zA5V9gc6jTpPq3pIuvC8?p=preview

[image]

Comment: I am able to see the updated model values. 
`c_1:true
c_2:true
c_3:true
c_4:false`

Comment: Click third checkbox one time then automatically first two checkbox will be checked and now check for model values

Comment: You aren't modifying model, you just modify attribute of output structure. You should operate on $scope.c_1 variables and set them true/false.

Comment: why are you putting for loop to update checkboxes ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar ok..suggest an alternate for for loop. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You should operate on `$scope` **inorder to achieve two-way binding.**

So, your function will change to,

```
function rangeCal(arg, bool){
    var tmparray= [];
    var selectedcheckbox;
    for(var propt in arraymatrix){
      tmparray = arraymatrix[propt];
      for(var i=0; i <= tmparray.length; i++){
        if(month === tmparray[i]){
          selectedcheckbox = propt;

          var a = 'c_'+selectedcheckbox;
          $scope[a]= true
          var gap = arg.split('_')[1];
          if(!bool){
            for(var j=propt; j<= gap; j++){

              var j = 'c_'+j;
              $scope[j]= true
            }
          }else if(bool) {
            for(var k=propt; k<= gap+1; k++){
               if(k > gap){
                var k = 'c_'+k;
                $scope[k]= false
               }

                var j = 'c_'+j;
                $scope[j]= true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

[**HERE IS THE WORKING PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLtm1Dq0YrQsPp0YwBdB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your idea but it affected my logic.. I can handle anyway :)

Comment: @Sharmila, I haven't changed logic much? is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+j)).attr('checked', true);
```

with

```
 var index = 'c_'+j;
 $scope[index]= true
```

and same process to make it unchecked by putting `false` in place of `true`

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet, hope this is what you were looking for. It is working for both actions, checking and unchecking.

```
function rangeCal(arg, bool){
  var tmparray= [];
  var selectedcheckbox;
  for(var propt in arraymatrix){
    tmparray = arraymatrix[propt];
    for(var i=0; i < tmparray.length; i++){
      if(month === tmparray[i]){
        selectedcheckbox = propt;
          angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+selectedcheckbox)).attr('checked', true);
        var gap = arg.split('_')[1];
        if(!bool){
          for(var j=propt; j<= gap; j++){
            var cb_id = "c_"+j;
            $scope[cb_id] = true;
            // angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+j)).attr('checked', true);
          }
        }else if(bool) {
          for(var k=4; k>= gap; k--){
             var gap_id = "c_"+k;
             $scope[gap_id] = false;
            // angular.element(document.querySelector('#c_'+gap)).attr('checked', false);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log($scope);
  }, 2000);
}
```